# Leer varios Json a la vez

Tags: php, json, hilos, script

Buenas tardes a todos.

Bueno, básicamente mi pregunta me tiene un poco estresado, buscando en toda la web.

Tengo una carpeta de archivos la cual esta guardando N archivos Json, cada archivo Json se está actualizando constantemente (Re-escribiéndose a si mismo). Esos datos que estoy recibiendo, tienen ciertos datos para ver la funcionalidad de un equipo de red (modem,routers,swich).

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo puedo hacer con PHP; un script, que me esté consultando a esa carpeta, leyéndome cada archivo json y viendo las ultimas modificaciones del mismo? y tengo otra duda ¿Puedo hacer las consultas para que se este actualizando sin necesidad de refrescar la pagina.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: la aplicacion que genera lo sarchivos json es accesible para cambiar codigo, o es una tercera aplicacion de la que solo sabemos que genera jsons?. Dichos archivos json leidos, interpretados, actualizados y volcados al disco, o solo son volcados? (es decir, hay una bbdd por ahi que tiene la info actualizada y esa app lee de bbdd y deja jsons en el directorio?)

Comment: Gracias por responder, respecto a tu pregunta es si y no, me explico... Hay una tercera aplicación de monitoreo que está generando los Json, está los genera y los coloca en una carpeta (check, ya está funcionando :D), pero al momento de mostrarlos en pantalla para darles un manejo, no tengo problema con un json, pero son 6 u 8 json para un equipo ejemplo( Módem), Y No, no hay ninguna BD por el momento, puesto que esos Json tengo la idea, no sé, sean dinámicos al Frontend.

Comment: Se puede hacer. Aunque PHP no está pensado para flujos asíncronos, se puede.  Pero tu pregunta no es específica y no es posible responderla, sino sólo opinar. Tendrías que plantear tú mismo algunas decisiones de arquitectura para poder responderlas de manera específica. Por ej: ¿Se pueden monitorear cambios a archivos en tiempo real en PHP? ¿Cómo emitir un evento y un payload hacia el browser desde PHP sin un request de por medio? ¿Cómo implementar un event-loop en PHP? esas serían dudas puntuales